# Dynamically change vuetify v-alert prop

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to change the v-alert component type from a method but I cannot seem to figure out how. Here is my code so far:

```
   <v-alert type="{{alertType}}">
    I'm a success alert.
  </v-alert>
```

I thought I could bind alertType to a data variable which I manipulate from a method but it does not seem to work. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the CSS Vuetify.js file. please check this [example](https://codepen.io/zahraKaramii/pen/mdwWBqB?editors=101) code and links import in the setting part.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-alert :type="types">
        I'm an alert with a top border and red color
      </v-alert>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

js code:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      types: "success"
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Using :type rather than type seems to return this error: [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "type". However regular type will not allow the binding. Any ideas?

Comment: there are 4 types in v-alert. If you use indefinite words, this error will occur

you can put these types in data()
type:
1-success
2-info
3-warning
4-error

Comment: I guess my issue was that I did not set the initial value as one of the 4 types. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Template syntax is not allowed inside attributes anymore. If you want to bind an attribute to a data property, you should use `v-bind:` or its shorthand `:`

```html
<v-alert v-bind:type="alertType">
    I'm a success alert.
</v-alert>
```

OR simply

```html
<v-alert :type="alertType">
    I'm a success alert.
</v-alert>
```